Trying to pull a registry key in Powershell but I'm getting the "Cannot find path because it does not exist" error and I know that's a dirty lie
I'm writing a Powershell script that will gather various information from the PC and out-file those values to a .txt, two of them being registry keys. Powershell pulls one specific key with no problem, but this other one will simply not capitulate, and I receive the error below.
This is the key I'm trying to retrieve:
$windisver = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion).DisplayVersion"

But this is the error I get every time, and the $windisver value appears in the text file as System.Object[].
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion).DisplayVersion' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\*my account*\Desktop\Temp\Script_test\test.ps1:4 char:15
+ ... indisver = (Get-ItemProperty -Path ("HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKLM:\SOFTWARE\....DisplayVersion:String) [Get-ItemProperty], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand


The closing parenthesis and double quotes are misplaced in your command:
$windisver = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion).DisplayVersion"

Also, you should change HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE to HKLM OR prepend Registry:: to the path (notice you should remove the colon (:) as well in this case:
$windisver = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion").DisplayVersion

See this Stack OverFlow answer for more information on the above.
Change your command to:
$windisver = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion").DisplayVersion


Thank you for your response. I made the corrections you suggested, and it now no longer returns an error, but it isn't pulling the registry value into the text document. It just outputs as System.Object[].

Thank you @FastEthernet. Your code was perfectly fine. The issue was that my concatenate. . .had an extra comma. . .
